# Complex SQL statement is getting the better of me

Tags: mysql

I know I must be something insanely silly but I am trying to query a database using a rather complex statement (at least, to me) and I get more rows than I would expect, would anyone know how to 'fix' this?

The tables that I am querying are created as follows:

```
glycoPeptide | CREATE TABLE `glycoPeptide` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `protein` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |

run   | CREATE TABLE `run` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `glycoPeptide` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `run` enum('spectrum','chromatogram') NOT NULL,
  `glycoType` enum('N','O') DEFAULT NULL,
  `glycoSite` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pepMass` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pepSeq` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `glycoPeptide` (`glycoPeptide`),
  CONSTRAINT `run_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`glycoPeptide`) REFERENCES `glycoPeptide` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |

spectrum | CREATE TABLE `spectrum` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `run` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `glycoform` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `spectrum` enum('m/z','intensity') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `run` (`run`),
  CONSTRAINT `spectrum_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`run`) REFERENCES `run` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |

precursor | CREATE TABLE `precursor` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `run` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `retentionTime` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `mzValue` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `chargeState` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `run` (`run`),
  CONSTRAINT `precursor_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`run`) REFERENCES `run` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |

binaryDataArray | CREATE TABLE `binaryDataArray` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `spectrum` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `arrayLength` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `EncodedLength` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `arrayData` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `spectrum` (`spectrum`),
  CONSTRAINT `binaryDataArray_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`spectrum`) REFERENCES `spectrum` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

I have some test data in there for 2 proteins (IgG and IgE). IgG contains only 1 run, containing only 1 glycosite and therefore only 1 'set' of binaryDataArrays. IgE contains 3 glycosites, therefore having 3 runs and each run can contain multiple spectrum (each a set of 2 binaryDataArray).

I use the following query (using JOINS would be prettier, I know):

```
select
  precursor.mzValue,
  glycoPeptide.protein,
  binaryDataArray.arrayLength,
  binaryDataArray.encodedLength,
  precursor.chargeState,
  run.pepMass,
  run.PepSeq
from
  precursor,
  glycoPeptide,
  binaryDataArray,
  spectrum,
  run
where
  run.glycoPeptide = glycoPeptide.id AND
  spectrum.run = run.id AND
  precursor.run = run.id AND
  binaryDataArray.spectrum = spectrum.id AND
  spectrum.spectrum like 'm/z' AND
  precursor.mzValue like '1196.79' AND
  glycoPeptide.protein like 'IgE' AND
  run.glycoSite like '252' AND
  run.glycoType like 'N';
```

Yielding for IgG a result like I would expect:

```
+---------+---------+-------------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------+
| mzValue | protein | arrayLength | encodedLength | chargeState | pepMass | PepSeq    |
+---------+---------+-------------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------+
|   933.4 | IgG     |       10301 |         22912 |           3 | 1189.   | EEQYNSTYR |
+---------+---------+-------------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

For IgE (using the statement above) I get the following result:

```
+---------+---------+-------------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------+
| mzValue | protein | arrayLength | encodedLength | chargeState | pepMass | PepSeq    |
+---------+---------+-------------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------+
| 1196.79 | IgE     |       10301 |        109880 |           3 | 1033.   | GTVNLTWSR |
| 1196.79 | IgE     |       10301 |         54940 |           3 | 1033.   | GTVNLTWSR |
| 1196.79 | IgE     |       10301 |         54940 |           3 | 1033.   | GTVNLTWSR |
+---------+---------+-------------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

While I would expect only 1 row here and I can't seem to get my mind around it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**-- EDIT 1 --**

The way I wrote the where clause should do exactly what joins do as far as I know so that should not be the issue...

**-- EDIT 2 --**

Sample data:

```
select * from glycoPeptide;
+----+---------+
| id | protein |
+----+---------+
|  1 | IgG     |
|  2 | IgE     |
+----+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from run;
+----+--------------+----------+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------------+
| id | glycoPeptide | run      | glycoType | glycoSite | pepMass | pepSeq          |
+----+--------------+----------+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------------+
|  1 |            1 | spectrum | N         |       297 | 1189.   | EEQYNSTYR       |
|  2 |            2 | spectrum | N         |       275 | 1516.   | NGTLTVTSTLPVGTR |
|  3 |            2 | spectrum | N         |       252 | 1033.   | GTVNLTWSR       |
|  4 |            2 | spectrum | N         |        99 | 1556.   | VAHTPSSTDWVDNK  |
+----+--------------+----------+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select * from precursor;
+----+-----+---------------+---------+-------------+
| id | run | retentionTime | mzValue | chargeState |
+----+-----+---------------+---------+-------------+
|  1 |   1 | 00:13:32      |   933.4 |           3 |
|  2 |   2 | 00:00:00      |  965.55 |           2 |
|  3 |   2 | 00:00:00      | 912.036 |           2 |
|  4 |   2 | 00:00:00      | 1127.06 |           3 |
|  5 |   3 | 00:00:00      | 1099.97 |           2 |
|  6 |   3 | 00:00:00      |  1153.9 |           3 |
|  7 |   3 | 00:00:00      | 1196.79 |           3 |
|  8 |   4 | 00:00:00      |  1109.5 |           2 |
|  9 |   4 | 00:00:00      | 1157.66 |           2 |
| 10 |   4 | 00:00:00      | 1225.66 |           2 |
| 11 |   4 | 00:00:00      | 1206.47 |           3 |
| 12 |   4 | 00:00:00      | 1328.31 |           3 |
| 13 |   4 | 00:00:00      | 1304.09 |           3 |
| 14 |   4 | 00:00:00      | 1165.04 |           2 |
+----+-----+---------------+---------+-------------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from spectrum;
+----+-----+-----------+-----------+
| id | run | glycoform | spectrum  |
+----+-----+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |   1 | G1F       | m/z       |
|  2 |   1 | G1F       | intensity |
|  3 |   2 | NULL      | m/z       |
|  4 |   2 | NULL      | intensity |
|  5 |   2 | NULL      | m/z       |
|  6 |   2 | NULL      | intensity |
|  7 |   2 | NULL      | m/z       |
|  8 |   2 | NULL      | intensity |
|  9 |   3 | NULL      | m/z       |
| 10 |   3 | NULL      | intensity |
| 11 |   3 | NULL      | m/z       |
| 12 |   3 | NULL      | intensity |
| 13 |   3 | NULL      | m/z       |
| 14 |   3 | NULL      | intensity |
| 15 |   4 | NULL      | m/z       |
| 16 |   4 | NULL      | intensity |
| 17 |   4 | NULL      | m/z       |
| 18 |   4 | NULL      | intensity |
| 19 |   4 | NULL      | m/z       |
| 20 |   4 | NULL      | intensity |
| 21 |   4 | NULL      | m/z       |
| 22 |   4 | NULL      | intensity |
| 23 |   4 | NULL      | m/z       |
| 24 |   4 | NULL      | intensity |
| 25 |   4 | NULL      | m/z       |
| 26 |   4 | NULL      | intensity |
| 27 |   4 | NULL      | m/z       |
| 28 |   4 | NULL      | intensity |
+----+-----+-----------+-----------+
28 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id, spectrum, arrayLength, encodedLength from binaryDataArray;
+----+----------+-------------+---------------+
| id | spectrum | arrayLength | encodedLength |
+----+----------+-------------+---------------+
|  1 |        1 |       10301 |         22912 |
|  2 |        2 |       10301 |          3092 |
|  3 |        3 |       10301 |         54940 |
|  4 |        4 |       10301 |        109880 |
|  5 |        5 |       10301 |         54940 |
|  6 |        6 |       10301 |        109880 |
|  7 |        7 |       10301 |        102408 |
|  8 |        8 |       10301 |        109880 |
|  9 |        9 |       10301 |        109880 |
| 10 |       10 |       10301 |         54940 |
| 11 |       11 |       10301 |         54940 |
| 12 |       12 |       10301 |        109880 |
| 13 |       13 |       10301 |         54940 |
| 14 |       14 |       10301 |        109880 |
| 15 |       15 |       10301 |        109880 |
| 16 |       16 |       10301 |         54940 |
| 17 |       17 |       10301 |         54940 |
| 18 |       18 |       10301 |        109880 |
| 19 |       19 |       10301 |        109880 |
| 20 |       20 |       10301 |         54940 |
| 21 |       21 |       10301 |        109880 |
| 22 |       22 |       10301 |         54940 |
| 23 |       23 |       10301 |         54940 |
| 24 |       24 |       10301 |        109880 |
| 25 |       25 |       10301 |         54940 |
| 26 |       26 |       10301 |        109880 |
| 27 |       27 |       10301 |        109880 |
| 28 |       28 |       10301 |         54940 |
+----+----------+-------------+---------------+
28 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**-- EDIT 3 --**

The data that is required currently can not be gathered from the database as one of the relations isn't in there (need to be able to link a spectrum to a precursor). I have to thank Mr. Radical and Jack for helping to uncover this flaw and have accepted Jack's answer because his notation of joins in the query is easier to read than how I did it.

Comment: I would suggest selecting all columns and find out why more than one row was selected. Perhaps you were missing another condition? Also, stop using `LIKE` for things that don't contain wildcards.

Comment: Without seeing the actual data I can't really say, but it would appear that the rows on binaryDataArray for that protein are not unique.

Comment: I am fiddling around with the version you suggested earlier but I am doubtful of one thing. You stated that there is a missing condition to link glycoPeptide to precursor (directly) which is true (conceptually, these 2 are linked via spectrum).

Comment: @Kickstart Correct, 1 protein can have hundreds of spectrum (consisting of 2 binaryDataArrays) but by using all the conditions in my where clause it should be unique (in my mind).

Comment: If there are 2 binaryDataArrays for each spectrum, then there is nothing to limit that to only one being brought back. Afraid to work it out we would need to see the relevant data. What is strange is that if you had 2 binaryDataArray records then I would expect 2 rows returned, or a multiple of 2 rows.

Comment: the spectrum that is the 'parent' so to say of a binaryDataArray specifies what type (X-coords or Y-coords) of binaryData it is and during the query i specify which set of data I want. The test data is not that big (except for the binaryData strings) should I send a dump somewhere?

Comment: I have the feeling that the linking of run is what is causing the problem somehow as the results seem to come in a multiple of 3 rows (3 runs for IgE).

Comment: @BasJansen could you provide some sample data? If it is not to  much data of course.

Comment: @Radical I have added the total contents of the columns in question (except the binary string) to the original question as EDIT 2.

Comment: @BasJansen I am working on it right now.

Comment: @BasJansen I am missing the data for the table precursor.

Comment: It is listed between run and spectrum

Comment: @BasJansen why do you expect one row? If you have an IgE protein you have 3 runs. Do you want the data in one cell (concated)?

Comment: Unless i am missing something IgE has 3 runs because there are 3 different glycoSites, i want the binaryDataArray that belongs to a 'm/z' spectrum of a selected 'precsuror.mzValue' and that should be only 1 row. In other words there is (or should be) only 1 binaryDataArray belonging for example to precursor.mzValue (965.55) on run.glycoSite (275) with spectrum.id (3 = an m/z spectrum) matching to glycoPeptide.protein (IgE).

Comment: Oke, but that has to do with joins. Lets start with the first join. From the table run we need all glycoPeptide with the same id.

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7818/13

Comment: That fiddle yields the same results as my original query

Comment: I just realized that joining spectrum to precursor on spectrum.run is the one causing problems but fixing that won't be easy o.O

Comment: Why not? Suspected that it had something to do with that link. If you could explain the relationship maybe I can help.

Comment: I fixed it in the sqlfiddle by simply adding an element to spectrum called precursor linking back to precursor id... I am not the one responsible for the Database however *shrug* which is why fixing it is difficult.

Comment: SQLFiddle link of my 'fix' (I only edited the final query to reflect the change to the DB however) is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0fff9/2

Comment: Maybe this helps, this site contains a visually representation of how joins work. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Comment: Did you solve your question?

Comment: I've worked out why the query gives the results that it does; not sure how to fix it though :)

Comment: @Mr. Radical: Yes, thank you for your time ;) I wouldn't have realized the flaw in the DB without your help.

Comment: @Jack: You can't, the DB has to be modified by for instance adding the field precursor to spectrum and joining the 2 fields on spectrum.precursor = precursor.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would rewrite your query like this; it's easier to see what the join conditions are and it keeps the where clause clean:

```
select
  precursor.mzValue,
  glycoPeptide.protein,
  binaryDataArray.arrayLength,
  binaryDataArray.encodedLength,
  precursor.chargeState,
  run.pepMass,
  run.PepSeq
from
  precursor
  inner join glycoPeptide on run.glycoPeptide = glycoPeptide.id
  inner join binaryDataArray on binaryDataArray.spectrum = spectrum.id
  inner join spectrum on spectrum.run = run.id
  inner join run on precursor.run = run.id
where
  spectrum.spectrum like 'm/z' AND
  precursor.mzValue like '1196.79' AND
  glycoPeptide.protein like 'IgE' AND
  run.glycoSite like '252' AND
  run.glycoType like 'N';
```

The problem with your query lies in the `spectrum` table. The join from `run` yields three rows with `spectrum.id` being 9, 11 or 13.

```
|  9 |   3 | NULL      | m/z       |
| 11 |   3 | NULL      | m/z       |
| 13 |   3 | NULL      | m/z       |
```

Comment: Aye, I noticed that too during the discussion with Mr. Radical. The database has to be changed to be able to access the data that is needed (by adding a field (precursor) to spectrum).

Answer (score -1):

MySql JOIN shall help you. Your question is too long so I am giving you a simple expample for JOIN

A table reference can be aliased using tbl_name AS alias_name or tbl_name alias_name:

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.salary
  FROM employee AS t1 INNER JOIN info AS t2 ON t1.name = t2.name;

SELECT t1.name, t2.salary
  FROM employee t1 INNER JOIN info t2 ON t1.name = t2.name;
```

For more detail visit:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: I will agree with Jack's answer (that is missing) that the syntax is easier using joins but isn't the criteria that I specify in the first few lines of my where doing exactly the same as a join?